# access sastrawi folder from command prompt

Tags: python, nlp, stemming

I am trying to access sastrawi folder

The following steps are done

I downloaded the Composer-Setup.exe file from composer page and got successfully installed.

I installed Composer-Setup in sastrawi folder

I get sastrawi folder from https://github.com/sastrawi/sastrawi

I executed the command for accees folder sastrawi in command prompt

**php composer.phar require sastrawi/sastrawi:^1**

This line generates the error message: could not open file composer.phar

how to resolve this error???

Comment: have you tried `composer update` command after going to the project directory ?

Comment: thank you, that's working for resolving error message. But, i still not found the result exactly i want, the result in command prompt should be like "**./composer.json has been update. Loading composer repositories with package information. Updating dependencies (including require-dev). Nothing to install or update. generating autoload files**" after i executed command "**php composer.phar require sastrawi/sastrawi:^1**"